# jQuery : load class on impression

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

I'm implementing a functionality that will not load comments in my website by default. Only when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, comments should load.

In below code snippet, what should I replace `click()` with, so that comments will load only on user impression of `div`.

```
<div class="show-comments"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show-comments').on('click', function () {
            // load comments code
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `scroll` event of your scrollable element and if the scroll position reaches to the position that you want then show the comments. Here you have an example to guide you in this task:

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="container"><!-- Your content --></div>
<div id="comments"><!-- Your comments here --></div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
var body = $("body"),
    comments = $("#comments"),
    win = $(window),
    near = 20,
    delay = NaN;

//---Show comments
function showComments() {

    comments.slideDown();

    win.off("scroll");

}

//---Check comments visibility
function checkCommentsVisibility() {

    if (!isNaN(delay)) {
        clearTimeout(delay);
    }

    delay = setTimeout(function() {

        var scrollHeight = body[0].scrollHeight - win.height();
        var scrollTop = body.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > scrollHeight - near) {

            showComments();

        }

    }, 100);

}

//---Scroll event
win.on("scroll", checkCommentsVisibility);
```

Here you have [a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/m3z2Ly57/) to show you the functionality.

But if you want to load comments by `Ajax` step by step, depending on the scroll position, I recommend you to use a plugin like [Scroll Magic](http://scrollmagic.io/).